# i am integrate afterpay payment gateway and facing the error that is my code

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway

```
$api_secret = '';
        $merchant_id = '';
        $base_url = 'https://global-api.afterpay.com';
       
        // Set the payment details
        $payment_data = [
            'amount' =>  $calculatedAmount,
            'currency' => 'AU',
            'description' => 'ToolTrade Payment',
            'payment_method' => 'afterpay',
            'confirm' => true,
            'merchant_id' => $merchant_id,
            'redirectUrl' => 'https://example.com/afterpay/callback',
        ];
        
        $client = new Client();
          $response = $client->post("$base_url/payments", [
            'json' => $payment_data,
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Basic '  . base64_encode("$api_secret"),
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
        ]);
        $response_data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

facing that error
Client error: `POST https://global-api.afterpay.com/payments` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:\n{\n        "errorCode": "unauthorized",\n        "errorId": "cf-worker",\n        "message": "unauthorized - Unable to rout (truncated...)\n"

Comment: and what exactly you're passing as: ``$api_secret`` ?

Answer (score 0):

The construction of the Authorization header may be incorrect. The format is usually like this: username:password.

```
'Authorization' => 'Basic '  . base64_encode("$api_key:$api_secret"),
```